# Unwanted transition effect on sticky header image when changing sizes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Apologies for the ambigious title, couldn't think of anything more descriptive. So basically I have a client that wants a header partway down the page, on that header as well as nav is an image (Guitar pick logo) that overlaps top and bottom. They also want a CSS3 transition that allows it to rotate. They also want the header to be sticky when it reaches the top as well as the overlapping logo to shrink in size to fit onto the bar and not overlap, cutting off the top.

I've got that all working and a rough version can be seen in this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/8puCE/6/

Now my problem is that in both Chrome and IE10 when the pick returns from small back to the original size the transition effect used for the spin is also being used, causing an unwanted delay in Chrome and the effect of the container box slowly getting bigger in IE. For some reason FF doesn't do either, jumping directly to small/large with no transition. This is what I want across all browsers, if possible.

From what I can tell the problem is because .front and .back have the transition on them for the spin, it's also obviously applying to the size transition as well, which I don't want.

Here is the code I'm currently using to stick the bar and adjust the logo to a smaller size:

```
var NavTop = $('#navbar').offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function(){
  if( $(window).scrollTop() > NavTop ) {
    $('#navbar').css({position: 'fixed', top: '0px'});
    $('#mainwrap').css({padding: '65px 0 0 0'});
    $('.flip-container').css({top: '2px' , height: '64px', width: '58px'});
    $('.front').css({background: 'url(images/logoc.png) no-repeat' , height: '64px', width: '58px'});
    $('.back').css({background: 'url(images/logoc.png) no-repeat' , height: '64px', width: '58px'});
  } else {
    $('#navbar').css({position: 'relative'});
    $('#mainwrap').css({padding: '0 20px'});
    $('.flip-container').css({display: 'inline', top: '-30px' , height: '138px', width: '121px'});
    $('.front').css({background: 'url(images/logoa.png) no-repeat' , height: '138px', width: '121px'});
    $('.back').css({background: 'url(images/logob.png) no-repeat' , height: '138px', width: '121px'});
  }
});
```

I'm using photobucket images in the jsfiddle but those are my real images. logoa is the front of the big one, logob is the back of the big one. logoc is the front of the small one and currently the back as well, but back will be logod in final.

Comment: I'm currently testing in Chrome and can't see the behavior you're talking about. It only spins if my mouse happens to pass over it during the scroll. Am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: I think I briefly see what OP means. While the guitar pick is transitioning from small to large it seems to get cropped by a container. I think this only happens if I turn "Experimental JavaScript Features" off in `chrome://flags`. Sometimes the pick jumps from the small state to the large state with no animation.

Comment: you havs 0.6 seconds for the first transition. change it to 0 seconds and it will be ok -- demo  -- http://jsfiddle.net/wqz4G/

Comment: @Tasos that works except after scrolling down and returning back up the flip animation no longer works properly.

Comment: Its Ok now, I fixed the animation by setting the transitions to 0, and then using a timeout function without a timer back to 0.6 seconds. It seems to do the trick. If its what you want ill put it as answer. --- http://jsfiddle.net/wqz4G/1/

Comment: @Tasos unfortunately I'm seeing the unwanted transition in IE10 and Chrome again with this latest update. The chrome one I can live with, it doesn't look too bad but the IE10 effect looks jarring, coming out of the resizing container.

Answer (score 0):

I have a strong suspicion you can express all of these animations without using a single line of JavaScript (save for the viewport position detection to set/remove the *fixed* mode). All those JavaScript style modifications might be messing with the animation timers.

Your JavaScript code should look like:

```
 $(window).scroll(function(){
   if( $(window).scrollTop() > NavTop ) {
     NavTop.addClass("fixed"); // or maybe $(document.body)? you don't seem to
                               // have a container element for both the header
                               // and the main content
   } else {
     NavTop.removeClass("fixed");
   }
});
```

Comment: Yeah thanks this seems useful to cut down on what I agree is very bloated/messy, but I can't see how I would apply all of those changes with this method, since I'm needing to alter several elements as you can see. Unless I'm not seeing it I don't think I could achieve all of that with just one extra class on the container.

Comment: Do you know that CSS supports selector paths? Such as: `body.fixed #mainwrap { padding: 0 20px; }` means if class `"fixed"` is on the body apply padding to `#mainwrap`. This allows you to change many elements by setting just one class.